# Excel Issue - ISblank ISerror and vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am having a few issues with this in excel.

First of all i want to wrap this in an ISERROR and can't quite get it correct.

=IF(ISBLANK(P8),(VLOOKUP(Q8,Testdata,3,FALSE)),(VLOOKUP(P8,Testdata,3,FALSE)))

Second i am saying if P8 is blank go query a different column, that seems to work other than the P8 column is a number in a text field, yet the lookup is also a number in a text field. I want it to be text lookup against text but excel is getting confused that its a number?

Q8 is text against text and that works fine, for example Q8 = "abcdefg" and the lookup finds it.

P8 is 123456 and the lookup is text as 123456, the datasource is actually text.

Need help.

Comment: to wrap it use `IFERROR` function

Comment: i know that is the issue i have, cant quite get the syntax correct

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this in IFERROR and replace "SomeOtherValue" with another range =IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(P8),(VLOOKUP(Q8,Testdata,2,FALSE)),(VLOO‌​KUP(P8,Testdata,2,FA‌​LSE))), "SomeOtherValue")

Comment: thanks but what is that fixing? help me understand, thanks

Comment: my original syntax pulls through data if it exists or n/a if not, your code just puts "Someothervalue" in every column........?

Comment: "Someothervalue" is the value that you want to see when there is an error, it may be a reference to a cell or any other string value, you can write "N/A" if you like. This is how IFERROR works, if formula do not return error gives the result of formula, if formula returns error then return what you want to return.

Comment: i think the issue is the numbers as text in column P6. The column is set to general and numbers are pasted in, they look up a table that has a column set to text thats stores numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Looking up a number stored as text in Excel needs the lookup "value" to be expressed as `TEXT` so you have to coerce your number into text.

You can convert P8 to text format using `TEXT(P8, "@") so your formula should be:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(P8),(VLOOKUP(Q8,Testdata,3,FALSE)),(VLOOKUP(TEXT(P8,"@"),Testdata,3,FALSE)))
```

Comment: in p8 i have 256-49-8 and in my lookup table "testdata" i have 256-49-8 but i am getting no match

Comment: Are both strings the same length?  There could be hidden characters like spaces in one or the other.